# How many times a number appears in succession without a break or change in number python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to find the max consecutive number of times a number has appeared. Specifically 1 or 0 . To clarify.

```
a = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1]
```

What I want python to do is count how many times 1 and 0 appeared in succession.

So for 1 the max it appeared in succession is 4 and for 0 the max succession is 3.

what I tried so far

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy 
l = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
x = sum(1 for i in l if i % [1])
print
```

x

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: furthermore, I tried, numpy range, count, numpy.max, numpymin but none of them work.

Comment: What's the size of the original list? Is performance a concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
max_of_1 = max([i for i in [[key,len(list(group))] for key, group in groupby(a)] if i[0]])[1]
max_of_0 = max([i for i in [[key,len(list(group))] for key, group in groupby(a)] if not i[0]])[1]
```

**Result**

```
In [1]: max_of_1
Out[1]: 4
In [2]: max_of_0
Out[3]: 3
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for easy 1 liner code thank you :)